# Как произвести проверку введено ли число или символ в строку при проверке на четность?

Tags: javascript

Есть задача. Написать программу для проверки чётности чисел что бы выдавало три результата (четное число, не четное число, или не число). Написал вот такой код:

```
Enter anumder <input type="text" id="1">
<button onclick="ch()">Check</button>

<script>

    function ch(){
       var a = document.getElementById("1").value;

        console.log (a)

        if (a % 2 == 0){
            alert ("Чётное") 
        }

        else if (a % 2 !== 0){
            alert ("Не чётное")
        } 

       **else if (a == ???){
            alert ("Не число")**

    }

</script>
```

Но не получаться сделать проверку если вводить в строку буквы или символы.
Подскажите возможно кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код, который решает вашу задачу:

HTML:

```html
Enter a number <input type="text" id="input">
<button id="button">Check</button>
```

JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const value = parseInt(document.querySelector('#input').value)

    if (isNaN(value)) {
      return console.log('Не число!')
    }

    if (value % 2 === 0) {
      return console.log('Чётное!')
    }

    else {
      return console.log('Нечетное!')
    }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)